# I accidentally commited my project folder in my first Git push. But I don't want to have a parent folder at all in Git. What can I do to fix this?

Tags: git, commit

For information, I'm new to Git, sorry for the dumb questions. Basically I have written some Java code in Eclipse, then created a new project in my local Gitlab server, and pushed my first code to the repo successfully.

The code structure in Eclipse was as follows:

- `project_name`

  - `MyClass.java`

When I pushed to Git, into the `project_name` repo, the result I got was this:

- `project_name`

  - `project_name`

    - `MyClass.java`

But I don't want to have the `project_name` twice. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Move the file out of the nested folder and into the parent folder and then delete the nested folder. Stage the changes. Commit. Push.

Comment: @JBallin There is no nested folder. It's just the root folder of my project in Eclipse. Eclipse doesn't allow code to exist without a parent folder.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you want your repository to look something like this

- Project Root Folder (e.g. "/my-webapp")

  - /.git (this is the hidden git folder which is created on `git init`)
  - /src (here resides your source code)

    - MyClass.java

Tbh, I would just create everything again clean from scratch. So delete your remote repo and your local folder (but save the .java file somewhere) and finally push your clean folder to the repo. Be aware to call the `git init` command from **inside the project root folder**.